# PDF generation from XHTML template

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, primefaces, flying-saucer

I have a template editor, it's implemented in JSF, PrimeFaces. In this template editor, user has possibility for adding different components. For each component can be configured:

- width, height;
- position;
- text content;

Full information related to these components is stored in XML. Width/height/position attributes are stored in pixels. 'Position' attribute is absolute position in relation to boundaries of template.

Currently, I have a task for preparing PDF of this template which is stored in XML. For now, I have an idea to create XHTML page with these components and positions, sizes from XML. For generating PDF, I have the button on template page. The action for this button - is getting the content from XHTML page and generating PDF by Flying Saucer library. Currently, I see that I have the issues with displaying needed data. The reason is different width of PDF page and template editor. All sizes and positions in pixels are not actual in PDF page. Can you give me advice how to correctly resolve the task of generating PDF from XHTML template? Maybe I should save positions, sizes in another format, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@page{}` in the css.